# Number in java how it work without a subclass?

Tags: java, numbers, abstract-class

I want to know why the result of this code:

```
Number x = 3;
System.out.println(x.intValue());
System.out.println(x.doubleValue());
```

generates

> 3
>   3.0

as Number is an **abstract** class in Java.

So when I need to use it - I could use it with some it's subclasses like Integer, Double ...etc. Now I want to know how exactly this part of code works:

```
Number x = 3;
```

Answer (score 4):

[Auto Boxing.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

So when you do

```
Number x = 3;
```

That gets compiled to

```
Number x = new Integer(3);
```

> > Number in java how it work without a subclass?

That is a wrong assumption. Number class have subclasses. If you look at the definition of Integer class.

Look at the definition of Integer class

```
public final class Integer
extends Number
```

It is a sublcass of Number so it gets compiled fine.

Comment: It's not really the same as `new Integer` though, as that would actually create a new instance, while Java would pool small Integer values. Maybe just replace "is compiled to" with "is roughly equivalent to" or similar?

Comment: @tobias_k I just don't want to inject more confusion. So just to demonstrate what really happen in this case and shown the example :)

Answer (score 4):

when you do:

```
Number x = 3;
System.out.println(x.intValue());
System.out.println(x.doubleValue());
```

Following will happen:

```
Number x = 3;
```

this will declare x as int, and will be auto boxed to an object of the class `Integer` turning this:  `Number x = 3;` into  `Number x = new Integer(3);`

then here:

```
System.out.println(x.intValue());
```

`intValue` is implemented as:

```
public int intValue() {
    return value;
}

System.out.println(x.doubleValue());
```

and `doubleValue` is implemented as:

```
public double doubleValue() {
    return (double)value;
}
```

Comment: I like your step by step explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The key thing to understand here: the fact that you use **Number** on the **left** hand side of that assignment doesn't mean that the object referenced by `x` is in fact a direct instance of the Number class.

As others have outlined, **auto-boxing** kicks in here. One way to get to the true nature of things: by looking at the byte code:

```
   0: iconst_3      
   1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   4: astore_1
```

...

`1:` is about calling `Integer.valueOf(int)` - the [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) that turns the int value `3` into an Integer object!

The other easy way to get to the point - by doing:

```
 System.out.println(x.getClass());
```

and that of course prints Integer; not Number!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the 'true nature' in the bytecode. I can't see the auto-boxing nor that it is auto-boxed into an Integer (and not into a Double or something else). Maybe you could comment on it or explain?

Comment: @dingalapadum You are correct - I reduced the bytecode output and explained the one line that really matters. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Ok. Thank you, but I'm still not getting how you can see that. I guess I will have to read about the java-bytecode in general... any suggestions where to start with that? Javadocs?

Comment: Your favorite search engine. Maybe here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html ...   the point is basically: all program content is there in bytecode, and the first thing we find is the invocation of that method. To be precise: first a constant (3) is pushed; then valueOf() is called ... to create that Integer object.

Answer (score 1):

**Autoboxing** helping to compile the code.

> Converting a primitive value (an int, for example) into an object of the corresponding wrapper class (Integer) is called autoboxing

So compiler convert this code `Number x = 3;` to the following at runtime :

```
Number x = Integer.valueOf(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of boxing and unboxing:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer x = 5; // boxes int to an Integer object
    x =  x + 10;   // unboxes the Integer to a int
    System.out.println(x); 
  }
}
```

This will produce the following result:

```
15
```

When x is assigned an integer value, the compiler boxes the integer because x is integer object. Later, x is unboxed so that they can be added as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a feature called AutoBoxing, what it does is automatically wrapping primitives with it's corresponding object wrapper class.

```
Number x=3;
System.out.println(x.getClass());
```

Just try this and you will see what actually has happened.

Also try

```
Number x=3.0;
System.out.println(x.getClass());
```

In first case java wraps 3 with an Integer.class and in the second time it wraps 3.0 with a Double.class.

In your case, since it is getting wrapped as an Integer, when you call doubleValue() method, it actually calls doubleValue() in Integer.class which has the following implementation.

```
public double doubleValue() {
    return (double)value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below hierarchy of Number DataType

**Direct Known Subclasses**:
*AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short*

[image: Number DataType Family]